# What exactly happens when a thread awaits a task inside a while loop?

Tags: c#, loops, async

After dealing with C#'s async/await pattern for a while now, I suddenly came to realization that I don't really know how to explain what happens in the following code:

```
async void MyThread()
{
    while (!_quit)
    {
        await GetWorkAsync();
    }
}
```

`GetWorkAsync()` is assumed to return an awaitable `Task` which may or may not cause a thread switch when the continuation is executed.

I wouldn't be confused if the await wasn't inside a loop. I'd naturally expect that the rest of the method (i.e. continuation) would potentially execute on another thread, which is fine.

However, inside a loop, the concept of "the rest of the method" gets a bit foggy to me.

What happens to "the rest of the loop" if the thread is switched on continuation vs. if it isn't switched? On which thread is the next iteration of the loop executed?

My observations show (not conclusively verified) that each iteration starts on the same thread (the original one) while the continuation executes on another. Can this really be? If yes, is this then a degree of unexpected parallelism that needs to be accounted for vis-a-vis thread-safety of the GetWorkAsync method?

UPDATE: My question is not a duplicate, as suggested by some. The `while (!_quit) { ... }` code pattern is merely a simplification of my actual code. In reality, my thread is a long-lived loop that processes its input queue of work items on regular intervals (every 5 seconds by default). The actual quit condition check is also not a simple field check as suggested by the sample code, but rather an event handle check.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it a performance hit to create threads that loop a lot to check for things?](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/198979/is-it-a-performance-hit-to-create-threads-that-loop-a-lot-to-check-for-things)

Comment: See also [How do yield and await implement flow of control in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42287737/how-do-yield-and-await-implement-flow-of-control-in-net) for some great information on how this is all wired together.

Comment: @John Wu:  I haven't seen that SO thread yet. Lots of interesting info nuggets there. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can actually check it out at [Try Roslyn](http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsB0AVAFgJ1QEMATSKHIkAaxAG4AoUc+JNdRgYwBsqQYACvgD2UfEXQMA3gxhyYKIsjCcYAN2FgSMALJFIACgCUs+TPkXdBgAxHGFgL6m5zmAAd8YNUtQLkSlRgAI2FhbhgAfQBHYDBke3lXRWVVKgQIVQ0tK0hkGEg3YGQTC3NLOQB3XDBuXwMAQmjY4tdyuSIK/TzsKmpMABFUXgQDAEZrWwS5JwcgA==).  Your await method gets rewritten into `void IAsyncStateMachine.MoveNext()` on the generated async class.

What you'll see is something like this:

```
            if (this.state != 0)
                goto label_2;
            //set up the state machine here
            label_1:
            taskAwaiter.GetResult();
            taskAwaiter = default(TaskAwaiter);
            label_2:
            if (!OuterClass._quit)
            {
               taskAwaiter = GetWorkAsync().GetAwaiter();
               //state machine stuff here
            }
            goto label_1;
```

Basically, it doesn't matter which thread you're on; the state machine can resume properly by replacing your loop with an equivalent if/goto structure.

Having said that, async methods don't necessarily execute on a different thread.  See Eric Lippert's explanation ["It's not magic"](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/11/04/asynchrony-in-c-5-0-part-four-its-not-magic/) to explain how you can have working `async/await` on only one thread.

Comment: I seem to be underestimating the extent of rewriting that compiler does on my async code. In essence, there is no "loop" after the rewrite! That was the missing part for me. Awesome and thank you for the 'Try Roslyn' link as well!

Comment: GOTO is the *original* loop construct. Let's not forget that.

Comment: that "try roslyn" link made understanding a lot more better

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, Servy has written some code in an answer to a similar question, upon which this answer is based:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22049339/how-to-create-a-cancellable-task-loop

Servy's answer includes a similar `ContinueWith()` loop using TPL constructs without explicit use of the `async` and `await` keywords; so to answer your question, consider what your code might look when your loop is unrolled using `ContinueWith()`

```
    private static Task GetWorkWhileNotQuit()
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

        Task previous = Task.FromResult(_quit);
        Action<Task> continuation = null;
        continuation = t =>
        {
            if (!_quit)
            {
                previous = previous.ContinueWith(_ => GetWorkAsync())
                    .Unwrap()
                    .ContinueWith(_ => previous.ContinueWith(continuation));
            }
            else
            {
                tcs.SetResult(_quit);
            }
        };
        previous.ContinueWith(continuation);
        return tcs.Task;
    }
```

This takes some time to wrap your head around, but in summary:

- `continuation` represents a closure for the *"current iteration"*
- `previous` represents the `Task` containing the state of the *"previous iteration"* (i.e. it knows when the 'iteration' is finished and is used for starting the next one..)
- Assuming `GetWorkAsync()` returns a `Task`, that means `ContinueWith(_ => GetWorkAsync())` will return a `Task<Task>` hence the call to `Unwrap()` to get the 'inner task' (i.e. the *actual* result of `GetWorkAsync()`).

So:

1. Initially there is no *previous* iteration, so it is simply assigned a value of `Task.FromResult(_quit)`  - its state starts out as `Task.Completed == true`.
2. The `continuation` is run for the first time using `previous.ContinueWith(continuation)`
3. the `continuation` closure updates `previous` to reflect the completion state of `_ => GetWorkAsync()`
4. When `_ => GetWorkAsync()` is completed, it "continues with" `_previous.ContinueWith(continuation)` - i.e. calling the `continuation` lambda again

   - Obviously at this point, `previous` has been updated with the state of `_ => GetWorkAsync()` so the `continuation` lambda is called when `GetWorkAsync()` returns.

The `continuation` lambda always checks the state of `_quit` so, if `_quit == false` then there are no more continuations, and the `TaskCompletionSource` gets set to the value of `_quit`, and everything is completed.

As for your observation regarding the continuation being executed in a different thread, that is not something which the `async`/`await` keyword would do for you, as per this blog *"Tasks are (still) not threads and async is not parallel"*.   - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benwilli/2015/09/10/tasks-are-still-not-threads-and-async-is-not-parallel/

I'd suggest it is indeed worth taking a closer look at your `GetWorkAsync()` method with regards to threading and thread safety.  If your diagnostics are revealing that it has been executing on a different thread as a consequence of your repeated async/await code, then something within or related to that method must be causing a new thread to be created elsewhere.  (If this is unexpected, perhaps there's a `.ConfigureAwait` somewhere?)

Comment: The code I've shown is (very) simplified. Inside GetWorkAsync() there are multiple further awaits. Some of them access the database and network, which means true I/O. As I understand, the thread switch is a natural consequence (albeit not required) of such awaits, because the initial thread doesn't establish any synchronization context that would govern where the continuations should execute. So they execute on a thread pool thread. Is my reasoning wrong?

Comment: @aoven Good point - I didn't consider the different kinds of `SynchronizationContext` - that is certainly important since `.ContinueWith()` uses the SynchronizationContext to dispatch the continuation; it would indeed explain the behaviour you're seeing if `await` is called on a ThreadPool thread or an ASP.NET thread.    A continuation could certainly be dispatched to a different thread in those cases.     On the other hand, calling `await` on a single-threaded context such as a WPF Dispatcher or Winforms context should be enough to ensure the continuation happens on the original. thread